# What ways exist to prevent Counterspell from being cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, counterspelling

#### What ways can a character (PC or Monster) prevent an enemy from casting counterspell?

What I can think of so far:

- Surprise the enemy and win initiative
- Cause the enemy to be incapacitated (or stunned/paralyzed/unconscious)
- Provoke the enemy into using a reaction earlier in the round (readied action, opportunity attack, previous spell)
- Avoid using perceivable spell components

  - Sorcerer subtle spell metamagic
  - Level 20 Druid [Archdruid](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/162450/60913) feature
- Prevent somatic components

  - The enemy is holding objects in both hands
- Block line of sight while casting the spell (As Medix2 [linked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/116752/60913) the spell can be readied behind cover)

  - Spells, Items, or Abilities such as *Fog Cloud*, *Darkness*, etc. that create areas of Heavy Obscurement
  - Use a spell or item that grants invisibility or heavy obscurement to a creature (Shadow of Moil, Invisibility)
  - Physical barriers such as walls or large creatures

Are there any other options available that I am missing? I would be interested both in a generic option that is missing and in any specific strategies that are not equivalent to something on my list.

I am asking because there are so many ways to prevent Counterspell that my initial list was unlikely to be comprehensive. Among the answers so far "using a spell that prevents reactions", "breaking line of sight", and "cast outside the range of 60 ft" are all options I hadn't considered and have helped to answer my question.

Comment: Related: "[Can I deny a counterspell by readying my spell behind full cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116751/36521)"

Comment: @Medix2 readying the spell behind full cover was an option I hadn't considered with regards to my initial list. Would it be alright if I amended my question to include it?

Comment: Since there aren't any answer, that should be alright to do (plus it's covered somewhere else already). That said, I'm worried that this question might not fit too well since what counts as a distinct way of preventing *counterspell* is rather iffy. Does being invisible count as "avoiding using perceivable components"? Does *antimagic field* count as "preventing somatic components"? Does simply just being out of the range of *counterspell* work? Though perhaps this question is a bounded list of sorts. If it is closed, I'd be happy to brainstorm things in chat

Comment: @Medix2 I will try to clarify what counts as individual examples. I don't want "cast behind a curtain, cast behind a pillar, cast behind a boulder" but the invisible example is distinct from the options I already listed.

Comment: What sort of answer(s) are you looking for? The community wiki answer below lists things like using a "spell that makes the enemy unable to use reactions" and then *also* lists the specific spells that do that. Are you looking for things as specific as those exact spells or just the more general idea of "prevent the enemy from taking reactions" without a listing of class features, spells, magic items, and so forth that accomplish this?

Comment: @Medix2 I don't expect answers to list every specific variation of a strategy (every spell that prevents reactions, every spell that can block line of sight). Listing the particular spells is helpful for me but I can also research that myself. I am looking for answers that fill gaps in my general thinking (such as my not thinking of casting the spell farther than 60 ft away).

Comment: Minor Illusion has a Somatic as well as Material component.  I don't see why that couldn't be noticed and counterspelled.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are absolutely right. I will remove that from my example to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As usual in questions that lead to considerably large lists (e.g. [What are the official, WotC-published classes and subclasses in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125278/43856)), I will post this as a community wiki answer and we can, as a community, update it with all possibilities.

## Spells / Abilities

**Make the enemy unable to use reactions**

- [Arms of Hadar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arms-of-hadar) (PHB, pg. 215)
- [Confusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/confusion) (PHB, pg. 224)
- [Shocking Grasp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shocking-grasp) (PHB, pg. 275)
- [Slow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) (PHB, pg. 277)
- [Staggering Smite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/staggering-smite) (PHB, pg. 278)
- Flurry of Blows (choice when using [Open Hand Technique](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheOpenHand), PHB, pg. 79)

**Force the enemy to use its reaction**

- [Dissonant Whispers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dissonant-whispers) (PHB, pg. 234)
- [Dominate Beast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-beast) (PHB, pg. 234)
- [Dominate Monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-monster) (PHB, pg. 235)
- [Dominate Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-person) (PHB, pg. 235)

**Allow the enemy to use its reaction**

- [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone) (PHB, pg. 287)
- [Provoke an opportunity attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks) (PHB, pg. 195)

**Make the enemy unable to cast spells**

- [Animal Shapes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-shapes) (PHB, pg. 212)
- [Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) (PHB, pg. 213)
- [Feeblemind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind) (PHB, pg. 239)
- [Mass Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-polymorph) (XGtE, pg. 160)
- [Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) (PHB, pg. 266)
- [True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) (PHB, pg. 283)
- [Illusory Reality](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofIllusion) <sup>1</sup> (PHB, pg. 118)

**Stopping their counterspell**

- [Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) (PHB, pg. 228)
- [Temporal Shunt](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/temporal-shunt) (EGtW, pg. 189)

**Prevent enemy from seeing you**

- *Invisibility*: [Greater invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-invisibility) (PHB, pg. 246), [Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invisibility)<sup>2</sup> (PHB, pg. 254), [Hidden Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/firbolg#FirbolgTraits) (VGtM, pg. 107)
- [*Blindness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Blinded) (PHB, pg. 290): [Blindness/deafness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blindness-deafness) (PHB, pg. 219), [Sunbeam](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sunbeam) (PHB, pg. 279), ...
- [Darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) (PHB, pg. 230)
- [*Heavily Obscured*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight) (PHB, pg. 183): [Fog cloud](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud) (PHB, pg. 243), [Cloudkill](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cloudkill) (PHB, pg. 222), ...

**Prevent enemy from targeting or affecting you**

- [*Globe of Invulnerability*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability) (PHB, pg. 245)

## Other means

**Make the enemy unable to use reactions**

- Cause any condition that stops them from using a reaction: [incapacitated, stunned, paralyzed, unconscious, petrified](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#AppendixAConditions) (PHB, pp. 290-292).

**Cast when the enemy is temporarily unable to use reactions**

- [Surprise](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Surprise) them and move before them

**Prevent conditions of counterspell from being met**

- Cast the spell outside the range (more than 60 ft.)

---

<sup>1 to equip them with armor they are not proficient in, if you accept "[Would forcing armour on a wizard using an illusion spell and Illusory Reality 'harm' them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/126213)"</sup>

<sup>2 It depends whether you believe the *invisibility* spell ends when a creature *finishes* casting a spell or *starts* casting a spell. This is explored more in the question "[Can you Counterspell a caster who is under Invisibility?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122700)"</sup>

Comment: Interestingly, the question "What are all the possible ways of taking away the reaction from an enemy" is included in this one.

Comment: Wouldn't things that prevent somatic components work as well (Tying up the spellcaster and similar)?

Comment: @Anagkai Feel free to add whatever you can think of or find, though I'm unsure exactly how specific of an answer the OP wants, so I've asked for clarification on that front

Comment: @Anagkai that works. You can edit it freely, it is a community wiki post, which means nobody "owns" it and nobody gets rep or whatever for it.

Comment: I'm thinking some sort of "force the enemy to be non-present" (Banishment, Hurl Through Hell)  might be appropriate as well.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't a complete answer as I'm sure other's will come up with more inventive options but your list misses some spells that are effective:

**Slow:**

> An affected target's speed is halved, it takes a -2 penalty to AC and
> Dexterity Saving Throws, **and it can't use Reactions**.

**Confusion**

Similar to Slow, it removes an affected creature's ability to take reactions.

Answer (score 7):

You can counterspell a counterspell to prevent it from affecting the original spell. It can also be prevented by simply being out of range of counterspell (60ft or 120ft with a sorcerer's distant spell).

You could also deny the enemy a reaction through multiple different effects such as Stun or slow.

All of your options seem pretty viable. If the person doesn't see the spell, they can't counterspell it.

Comment: A small point: Distant Spell *technically* [doesn't work with *counterspell*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128511) because the spell description includes a distance, not just its range

Comment: "effecting" should be "affecting" (1 character edits aren't allowed or I'd suggest it that way)

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to counterspelling *counterspell*, the spell [*temporal shunt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/temporal-shunt) (*Explorer’s Guide to Wildemount*, pg. 189) will also get the job done if the target fails its save:

> You target the triggering creature, which must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or vanish, being thrown to another point in time and causing the attack to miss or the spell to be wasted.

It has a casting time of 1 reaction “taken when a creature you can see makes an attack roll or starts to cast a spell”.

This spell also has some powerful tactical uses. The target disappears until the start of its next turn, and upcasting it allows you to target additional creatures.