# What spells take away an enemy's Reaction?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, reactions

I know the cantrip Shocking Grasp removes an enemy's ability to use its Reaction if you hit:

> ... On a hit, the target takes 1d8 lightning damage, and it can't take reactions until the start of its next turn.

I am not very familiar with the spells available but am theory-crafting a caster. Assuming you can take from any class spell list, what other spell options are there if I am looking to take away an enemy's reaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ripping off the first section of [this CW answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/171224/62294):

##### Make the enemy unable to use reactions

- [Arms of Hadar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arms-of-hadar) (PHB, pg. 215)
- [Confusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/confusion) (PHB, pg. 224)
- [Shocking Grasp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shocking-grasp) (PHB, pg. 275)
- [Slow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) (PHB, pg. 277)
- [Staggering Smite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/staggering-smite) (PHB, pg. 278)
- [Tasha's Mind Whip](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tashas-mind-whip) (TcE, pg. 115)

##### Force the enemy to use its reaction

- [Dissonant Whispers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dissonant-whispers) (PHB, pg. 234)
- [Dominate Beast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-beast) (PHB, pg. 234)
- [Dominate Monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-monster) (PHB, pg. 235)
- [Dominate Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-person) (PHB, pg. 235)

Comment: It looks like D&D Beyond changed its website; all links now land you on the front page where you're encouraged to spend a great deal of money on the handbooks.

Comment: @Shadur That is only links reference non-open content you need a subscription for (for example from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything or Arms of Hadar, which is not open). The other links still work without it.